# Saxon-HE integrated extension function: How to get a Processor object from a Configuration object when running an XQuery script?

Tags: java, xquery, saxon

I'm trying to get the Processor object from a Configuration object with an integrated extension function in an XQuery script (ran from `net.sf.saxon.Query`). If I do this, the variable `processor` is null:

```java
public class MyFunctionCall extends ExtensionFunctionCall {
    public Sequence call(XPathContext ctxt, Sequence[] params) throws XPathException {
        Processor processor = (Processor) ctxt.getConfiguration().getProcessor();
        // Abbreviated
    }
}
```

However, when doing an XSLT transformation (from `net.sf.saxon.Transform`), the variable is a proper `Processor` object.

I am doing the query from the command line, extending `net.sf.saxon.Query` and overriding `applyLocalOptions` in order to register my extension function.

My end goal is to get a `DocumentBuilder` object, and `Processor.newDocumentBuilder()` seemed the easiest way, but perhaps there is a workaround in this situation.

Comment: Not sure, perhaps the processor constructor taking a configuration which the Query method seems to use lacks a call to do `config.setProcessor(this)`: https://saxonica.plan.io/projects/saxon/repository/he/revisions/master/entry/latest10/hej/net/sf/saxon/s9api/Processor.java#L85 versus https://saxonica.plan.io/projects/saxon/repository/he/revisions/master/entry/latest10/hej/net/sf/saxon/s9api/Processor.java#L100 which seems to be used in the Transform class.

Comment: Perhaps using the buildDocumentTree method of the Configuration https://www.saxonica.com/html/documentation/javadoc/net/sf/saxon/Configuration.html#buildDocumentTree-javax.xml.transform.Source- suffices for your needs as a workaround so you don't need to access Processor or DocumentBuilder.

Comment: @MartinHonnen I don't think `buildDocumentTree` is quite what I had in mind because I don't have a `javax.xml.transform.Source`. The reason I want a `DocumentBuilder` is to obtain a `BuildingStreamWriter` and construct a `NodeInfo` using `XMLStreamWriter` methods.

Comment: Let's see what Saxonica/Michael Kay has to say, to me it seems the way the Query method sets up is Configuration and Processor it lacks the code to connect the Processor to the Configuration. If you want to build documents on the fly from a certain configuration Saxon 10 there is also https://www.saxonica.com/documentation/index.html#!javadoc/net.sf.saxon.sapling/SaplingDocument.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at the code, I think that the way we create the Configuration from the Query command line, it doesn't have an owning Processor, so with command line execution "out of the box", this can't be done.

However, since you're overriding `net.sf.saxon.Query` with your own subclass, you could override `parseOptions()` to do

```
config.setProcessor(processor);
super.parseOptions(options);
```

Transform provides an initializeConfiguration() hook for subclasses, this is sadly missing in Query.

Comment: Thanks, setting the processor like that worked a charm!